# Show ruby on rails server side form validation on a particular input element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

What I want is that I want to show error just below every input fields. For example I have two fields name and description,then it should display error relating to name just below the name input fields and description just below the description input field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've recently started using [`client_side_validations`](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations), and it's pretty nice. You essentially just need to add `:validate => true` to your forms:

```
<%= form_for @model, :validate => true do |f| %>
```

You may need to add some custom JavaScript too. Check out [the RailsCast for it](http://railscasts.com/episodes/263-client-side-validations) too.

Comment: It's a great gem but I　wonder whether the server-side validations still work or not ?

Comment: @SachinPrasad This doesn't preclude server-side validation. It's best to use both, but client-side validation is never a replacement for server-side.

Comment: @user1022209 This shouldn't affect server-side validations at all. It's supplementary.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can use something like this:
This is what that can be used for email input field

```
<tr>
   <div>
    <td>   <%= u.label :email %></td>
    <td>   <%= u.text_field :email, size: 30 %> </td>
    <td>
      <% if @user.errors[:email].any? %>
        <%= @user.errors[:email].join(",") %>
      <% end %>
    </td>
   </div>
  </tr>
```

similarly you can use it for textarea